# problem with copying charts to powerpoint

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have a simple macro that copies some charts from an excel file to a PowerPoint presentation.
It works most of time.
Sometimes it gives a runtime 13 error, type mismatch at random positions.
I have looked through the code and can only conclude that the error is in the shapes part, since it copies the chart to PowerPoint, but doesn't change its size or position.
I have included the sub that does the copying part.

```
Sub copiarChartPPT(ByVal sector As Integer, ByVal nchart As Integer, ByVal myPresentation As Object, ByVal s6s As Boolean, ByVal chartnum As Integer)

Dim pslide As Integer
Dim chartname As String
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object


'Copiar o grafico
Workbooks(arq).Activate
Sheets("LNCELL").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(chartnum).Chart.ChartArea.Copy


'Colar no powerpoint
If s6s Then
'6 Sectores
    If sector = 1 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "B")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "C")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "D")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "E")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "F")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 2 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "I")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "J")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "K")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "L")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "M")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 3 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "P")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "Q")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "R")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "S")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "T")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 4 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "W")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "X")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "Y")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "Z")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AA")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 5 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AD")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AE")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AF")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AG")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AH")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 6 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AK")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AL")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AM")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AN")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 26, "AO")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
    '3 Sectores
Else
    If sector = 1 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "B")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
        With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "C")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "D")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "E")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "F")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 2 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "I")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "J")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "K")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "L")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "M")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ElseIf sector = 3 Then
        pslide = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "P")
        Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides(pslide)
        mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2
        Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
            With myShape
            .LockAspectRatio = False
            .Left = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "Q")
            .Top = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "R")
            .Width = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "S")
            .Height = Sheets("Config").Cells(nchart + 1, "T")
        End With
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Which line or lines tend to be highlighted when you get the error?

Comment: thats one of the problems, even using F8 for a step by step, as soon as the first charts is copied the rest of the code runs for itself.

Comment: If you get an error message, and you click Debug, execution will be paused, and a line of code will be highlighted.